# drawing poly with holes in on android

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, polygon

i have a master polygon, then i have regions i dont want to be drawn inside, specified as other polygons. I'm using android 1.6 which I think has some form of opengl es 1.x. I've been reading up on the stencil buffer, can this be used to achieve what I need or is there another way?

Comment: The question is not complete and does not provide enough information on how to be answered properly.

Comment: I'll phrase it another way. How can I use opengl's stencil buffer to draw a polygon with holes in it? and does the version of opengl es on android 1.6 support stencil buffers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ES1.1 and ES2.0 support stencil operations.

However, you must enable the stencil buffer in the initial EGL configuration using the appropriate configuration options in the function eglChooseConfig.

For a complete documentation on the aforementioned function, please refer to the official knronos documentation:

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/eglChooseConfig.html